# Translating threejs animation from WebGL to Canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js, webgl

I am trying to make this threejs example (currently using WebGLRenderer) work with the CanvasRenderer:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_shadowmap.html

Here is my result:
http://scottrogowski.com/ralphe/horse2.html

I have went ahead and changed the renderer from WebGLRenderer to CanvasRenderer but past this I don't know what to do.  The horses float across the screen instead of running.

Is there something I am missing or am I running up against some inherent limit in ThreeJS?

I am guessing this might have something to do with `morphanimmesh` since this appears to be where the animation is happening.

The javascript code (tried to make a fiddle, wouldn't render :( ):

```
var SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH = 2048,
var SHADOW_MAP_HEIGHT = 1024;

var MARGIN = 100;

var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight - 2 * MARGIN;
var FLOOR = -250;

var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
var container, stats;

var NEAR = 5,
    FAR = 3000;

var sceneHUD, cameraOrtho, hudMaterial;

var morph, morphs = [];

var light;

var clock = new THREE.Clock();

init();
animate();


function init() {

    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    // SCENE CAMERA

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(23, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
    camera.position.set(700, 50, 1900);

    controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls(camera);

    controls.lookSpeed = 0.0125;
    controls.movementSpeed = 500;
    controls.noFly = false;
    controls.lookVertical = true;
    controls.constrainVertical = true;
    controls.verticalMin = 1.5;
    controls.verticalMax = 2.0;

    controls.lon = -110;

    // SCENE

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x59472b, 1000, FAR);

    // LIGHTS

    var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x444444);
    scene.add(ambient);

    light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1, 0, Math.PI, 1);
    light.position.set(0, 1500, 1000);
    light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    light.castShadow = true;

    light.shadowCameraNear = 700;
    light.shadowCameraFar = camera.far;
    light.shadowCameraFov = 50;

    //light.shadowCameraVisible = true;

    light.shadowBias = 0.0001;
    light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;

    light.shadowMapWidth = SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH;
    light.shadowMapHeight = SHADOW_MAP_HEIGHT;

    scene.add(light);

    createHUD();
    createScene();

    // RENDERER

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); //WebGLRenderer( { clearColor: 0x000000, clearAlpha: 1, antialias: false } );
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    renderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
    renderer.domElement.style.top = MARGIN + 'px';
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color, 1);
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    //

    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

    // STATS

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    //container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

    //

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {

    SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight - 2 * MARGIN;

    camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    controls.handleResize();

}

function createHUD() {

    cameraOrtho = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(SCREEN_WIDTH / -2, SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / -2, -10, 1000);
    cameraOrtho.position.z = 10;

    var shader = THREE.UnpackDepthRGBAShader;
    var uniforms = new THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(shader.uniforms);

    hudMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
        fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
        uniforms: uniforms
    });

    var hudGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH / 2, SHADOW_MAP_HEIGHT / 2);
    var hudMesh = new THREE.Mesh(hudGeo, hudMaterial);
    hudMesh.position.x = (SCREEN_WIDTH - SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH / 2) * -0.5;
    hudMesh.position.y = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - SHADOW_MAP_HEIGHT / 2) * -0.5;
    hudMesh.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

    sceneHUD = new THREE.Scene();
    sceneHUD.add(hudMesh);

    cameraOrtho.lookAt(sceneHUD.position);

}

function createScene() {

    // GROUND

    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xffdd99
    });
    planeMaterial.ambient = planeMaterial.color;

    var ground = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, planeMaterial);

    ground.position.set(0, FLOOR, 0);
    ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
    ground.scale.set(100, 100, 100);

    ground.castShadow = false;
    ground.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(ground);

    // TEXT

    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry("THREE.JS", {

        size: 200,
        height: 50,
        curveSegments: 12,

        font: "helvetiker",
        weight: "bold",
        style: "normal",

        bevelThickness: 2,
        bevelSize: 5,
        bevelEnabled: true

    });

    textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
    var centerOffset = -0.5 * (textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x);

    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        specular: 0xffffff,
        ambient: 0xaa0000
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textMaterial);
    mesh.position.x = centerOffset;
    mesh.position.y = FLOOR + 67;

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(mesh);

    // CUBES

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1500, 220, 150), planeMaterial);

    mesh.position.y = FLOOR - 50;
    mesh.position.z = 20;

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(mesh);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1600, 170, 250), planeMaterial);

    mesh.position.y = FLOOR - 50;
    mesh.position.z = 20;

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(mesh);

    // MORPHS

    function addMorph(geometry, speed, duration, x, y, z, fudgeColor) {

        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xffaa55,
            morphTargets: true,
            vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors
        });

        if (fudgeColor) {

            material.color.offsetHSL(0, Math.random() * 0.5 - 0.25, Math.random() * 0.5 - 0.25);
            material.ambient = material.color;

        }

        var meshAnim = new THREE.MorphAnimMesh(geometry, material);

        meshAnim.speed = speed;
        meshAnim.duration = duration;
        meshAnim.time = 600 * Math.random();

        meshAnim.position.set(x, y, z);
        meshAnim.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;

        meshAnim.castShadow = true;
        meshAnim.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add(meshAnim);

        morphs.push(meshAnim);

    }

    function morphColorsToFaceColors(geometry) {

        if (geometry.morphColors && geometry.morphColors.length) {

            var colorMap = geometry.morphColors[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < colorMap.colors.length; i++) {

                geometry.faces[i].color = colorMap.colors[i];

            }

        }

    }

    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

    loader.load("horse.js", function (geometry) {

        morphColorsToFaceColors(geometry);

        addMorph(geometry, 550, 1000, 100 - Math.random() * 1000, FLOOR, 300, true);
        addMorph(geometry, 550, 1000, 100 - Math.random() * 1000, FLOOR, 450, true);
        addMorph(geometry, 550, 1000, 100 - Math.random() * 1000, FLOOR, 600, true);

        addMorph(geometry, 550, 1000, 100 - Math.random() * 1000, FLOOR, -300, true);
        addMorph(geometry, 550, 1000, 100 - Math.random() * 1000, FLOOR, -450, true);
        addMorph(geometry, 550, 1000, 100 - Math.random() * 1000, FLOOR, -600, true);

    });


}

//

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    render();
    stats.update();

}

function render() {

    var delta = clock.getDelta();

    for (var i = 0; i < morphs.length; i++) {

        morph = morphs[i];

        morph.updateAnimation(1000 * delta);

        morph.position.x += morph.speed * delta;

        if (morph.position.x > 2000) {

            morph.position.x = -1000 - Math.random() * 500;

        }

    }

    controls.update(delta);

    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CanvasRenderer` does not support shadows.

You can fake shadows, however, as in [this](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_cube.html) example.

three.js r.58

Comment: I just got rid of all the shadow code. It didn't change anything so you are correct in that. The horses are still not running however. Any more tips?

Comment: `CanvasRenderer` does not support morph targets or `ShaderMaterial` either. r.58

Comment: Tried that now too. Is there a source where you are finding what is supported?

Comment: Study the three.js canvas examples. If a feature is supported, you will find an example of it.